# Creating Sling Models from resource paths

Tags: aem, sling, sling-models

I would like to instantiate a Sling Model from a JSP using a path to a resource like

```
<sling:adaptTo adaptable="/path/to/my/resource"  adaptTo="org.apache.sling.models.it.models.MyModel" var="model"/>
```

Within the the Sling Model, I would like to access properties of the specified resource via `@ValueMapValue` annotations.

My question is, how can I adapt my Sling Model to a resource path String so that I can inject the properties of the specified resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sling:getResource` EL Function provided by Sling could be used in conjunction with the `sling:adaptTo` tag which you are endevoring to use:

```
<sling:adaptTo adaptable="${sling:getResource(resourceResolver,'/path/to/my/resource')}" adaptTo="org.apache.sling.models.it.models.MyModel" var="model"/>
```

Full documentation concerning the available tags can be found [on the Sling site](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/sling-scripting-jsp-taglib.html).

Comment: Great suggestion! I think this is a good way to avoid Java code in JSPs. I am still curious how I could adapt a Sling Model to a resource path directly, but your solution might be more elegant and less effort.